# Extending Semiring $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ through exact sequence

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra, semigroups

I am working on extensions in the form of 
$$A\hookrightarrow B\twoheadrightarrow C$$
in my thesis and I am just wanting to add as an extra note, IF POSSIBLE, this. We have that that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to 
$$\frac{\mathbb{N}\oplus\mathbb{N}}{\Delta}$$
Where $\Delta=\{i\oplus i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ when it comes to semirings, for quotients of semirings we have that $a\cong b$ in $R/I$ if there exists $i,j\in I$ such that $a+i=b+j$ and addition is done component wise, e.i $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ along with the multiplication $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+bd,ac+bd)$. I have checked (partially from peano) that this works out and makes sense which it does. However my question is more along with this, we have the homomorphism $\imath:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $\imath(x)=(x,0)$ and as such we have
$$\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{\imath}\mathbb{Z}$$
which is clearly monomorphic, however my question is this, does there exist a homomorphism $\pi$ such that the following sequence is exact for some $X$?
$$\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{\imath}\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\pi}X$$
I know that we have that $\Delta$ must naturally be mapped to $0$ and $\mathbb{N}\oplus0$ must also be in the kernal, however I am having trouble to figure out if this homomorphism between semirings exists or not, does it?

Comment: Do you assume existence of a unit or not ?

Comment: From my understanding $0$ and $1$ are most commonly assumed in semi-rings which can be debated but considering this time we are dealing with $\mathbb{N}$ we have both anyway.

Comment: The thing is, it's not completely clear to me what an exact sequence of semi-rings is supposed to be. Is there a canonical definition ? Because if you assume your morphisms to be unital then the image of a morphism cannot be the kernel of another (except in very trivial cases).

Comment: Care to elabroate what you mean with the canonical definition? I have primarely operated on modules and such and I am doing a great leap of faith here hoping it is possible.

Comment: Well, I'm asking what you mean by "exact sequence". Usually the term is used is abelian categories, or at the very least in exact categories, but the category of semi-rings is not even preadditive (the sum of two semi-ring morphisms is not a semi-ring morphism). And you can't even blindly imitate the usual definition and say that a sequence $X\to Y\to Z$ is exact when the kernel of $Y\to Z$ is equal to the image of $X\to Y$ because it almost never happens (since $1$ can't be in the kernel if $Z\neq 0$). So I don't know what an exact sequence is supposed to be.

Comment: That would indeed be quite the issue, an issue I had not considered due to ignorance. Is there anyway to make it viable through a similar mean or is this concept completly unsalvagable?

Comment: Perhaps you could check this question and its answer : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83080/exact-sequence-of-monoids

Comment: Thanks, feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it os you get the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Captain Lama commented, the usual definition of "exact sequences" doesn't work well at all for semirings (or rings, for that matter).  Specifically, if $f:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of semirings and $Q\subseteq R$ is a subring of $R$ such that $Q\subseteq\ker{f}$, then $S$ must be the zero semiring (i.e., the semiring with one element).  Indeed, since $Q$ is a subring, it must contain $1$, so $f(1)=0$.  But a homomorphism of semirings must send $1$ to $1$, and so this means $1=0$ in $S$.  It follows that for any $s\in S$, $s=s\cdot 1=s\cdot 0=0$.  Thus $S$ has only one element.

This means that if you were ever to have an "exact sequence of semirings" $Q\stackrel{i}\to R\stackrel{f}\to S$ in the sense that $\operatorname{im}(i)=\ker(f)$, then $i$ is surjective and $S=\{0\}$, since $\operatorname{im}(i)$ is always a subsemiring of $R$.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately :< It would have been a great thing for me, know any source that can make any "sense" of it?